# How to append csv files side by side and repeat the same at the end using python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a problem in appending the csv files again. I have to append them side by side for the first set and repeat the same for four sets. With the help of others posts here, I have tried to append them. But they are getting appended at the next line. Please help me in getting through this problem.

Assume that split is a file which is same for all four sets: Final file should be something like this

split file:

vcc temp

1    13

2    15

measurement file1

c i

1 4

2 6

measurement file 2

c i

3 7

7 9

Measurement file 3.....file 4... same like the above

Final file should be like this:

vcc temp c i

1    13  1 4

2    15  2 6

1    13  3 7   --- this is second set

2    15  7 9

.....          ----for all 4 measurement files

I want the headers only for the first set.

The code I have tried is something like this:

```
def appenddata(fin,fin2,finalappend):

    if(flag==1):

        print('Inside If:',flag)
        with open(fin, 'r', newline='') as f:
            r = csv.reader(f)
            dict2 = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in r}

        with open(fin2, 'r', newline='') as f:
            r = csv.reader(f)
            dict1 = OrderedDict((row[0], row[1:]) for row in r)

        result = OrderedDict()
        for d in (dict1, dict2):
            for key, value in d.items():
                result.setdefault(key, []).extend(value)

        with open(finalappend, 'a+', newline='') as f:
            w = csv.writer(f)
            for key, value in result.items():
                w.writerow([key] + value)
        global flag
        flag = 0
        return(f.name)
    else:
        print(flag)
        with open(fin, 'r', newline='') as f:
            r = csv.reader(f)
            header=next(r)
            dict2 = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in r}

        with open(fin2, 'r', newline='') as f:
            r = csv.reader(f)
            header=next(r)
            dict1 = OrderedDict((row[0], row[1:]) for row in r)

        result = OrderedDict()
        for d in (dict1, dict2):
            for key, value in d.items():
                result.setdefault(key, []).extend(value)

        with open(finalappend, 'a', newline='') as f:
            w = csv.writer(f)
            for key, value in result.items():
                w.writerow([key] + value)
        return(f.name)
    flag=1
    num = int(input())
    finalfile=input()
    split = input()  
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        print (r'Enter the input measurement', i ,'file name with path:' )
        measurement = input()
        resultdata = appenddata(split,measurement,finalfile)
        #print ("final result:",resultdata )
```

The output that I got is
split
Measuremt1
split
measurement2
split
measurement3

Any suggestions and help would be greatly appreciated. I think I am going wrong in the appending part. Let me know how to get this done.

Note: I am using python 3.3
Previously I appended only one set by opening the final file in w mode. But now as there are 4 sets, I have changed the mode to a. This 'a' mode changed the total appending style.

Comment: Please include a sample of the input files and desired output

Comment: @DanielJimenez Yes I have included the sample of input files and the desired output. Your help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: In general I would recommend these steps: First write a simple parser to load the data into the interpreter. Although it looks complicated I advice to load the data into custom classes. Second transform the data in the memory the way you need it. Third serialize the data (write it to a file). These three distinct steps help very often. It fails if your data is bigger then your memory. I guess your data fits into the memory.

Comment: @guettli.. Im sorry. I didnt understand what you said. Im new to python programming. Could you explain it with code? Also my data will be huge.

Comment: @rami92 I guess you are new to programming, not just python programming. That's ok. You need to learn to cut big problems into smaller pieces. That's more important than code you are asking for.